# AWS Sumerian mobile(interface)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sumerian

I am working on AWS Sumerian as my POC. I published the link in Sumerian it's working fine on my PC. But, When I did open the link on my phone its just displaying the host, But not responding.
Note: it's should work on my mobile as how works on pc.

Can anyone suggest me the idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know what state machine you have used for response.
according to me, you have been used some keyboard UP & DOWN event?
Please correct my understanding.
If yes
then you need to change the state machine from UP & down to click/tab on entity event.

Hope, it help.
thanks.

Comment: Which event to use after integrating it with VR headset??

Answer (score 0):

For touch screen navigation behavior, make two states. Define the following:

1. No Movement state
   Add action: Mouse Up/ Touch End
2. Forward State
   Add action: a. Move (translation set to 0, 0, -5)  #can be changed according to your use case
   b. Mouse down/Touch start

Now connect these two states back and forth. It may solve your problem.